# How to get data by using different column values refrencing same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
create table 
books (
       id int
      ,bookname text
      );
```

---

```
create table 
users(
      id int
     ,name text
     ,book_1 int
     ,book_2 int
     ,book_3 int
     );
```

Now, 'book_1', 'book_2', 'book_3' contains id of table 'books'.

I am trying to create a single query using join to get the all three book names with user name.

I am able to get one book name, but how will I get all the three books name?

```
SELECT user.name
      ,books.name 
FROM user LEFT JOIN books ON books.id=user.book_1;
```

(This is giving me one book detail)

Using PostgreSQL.

I want result in one row. like

```
username, book_1_name, book_2_name, book_3_name
```

Don't want multiple rows.

Comment: can you provide sample data and create script of both tables ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *sub-selects* to get *bookname* of each *username* in a single row (**if *id* in table *books* is unique**)

```
select name username
      ,(select bookname from books where id=book_1) book1_name
      ,(select bookname from books where id=book_2) book2_name
      ,(select bookname from books where id=book_3) book3_name
from users
```

[**> SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c6d64/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user.name
      ,books.name
FROM user LEFT JOIN books ON books.id=user.book_1
          OR books.id=user.book_2 
          OR books.id=user.book_3;
```

join on all `id's`

Comment: You might want OR instead of AND id cant be all 3 values at the same time.

Comment: @Mihai yup thanx .. didnt recognise

Comment: @POHH Thanks for the answer, but I think it will give more than one row in result. I want a single row, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
SELECT user.name
      ,books.name 
FROM user LEFT JOIN books ON books.id in (select id from  books)
```

---

Comment: @koushikveldana Thanks for the answer, but I think it will give more than one row in result. I want a single row, I updated the question.